# how should I report question or answer posted using different language?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In my review queue I have got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879014/1831520), I can't tell which language the answer is but definitely not English, in that case how can I flag or report this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag it as "Not an answer", since no one except *maybe* those that speak/understand that language could discern if it is an answer or not.