# When should I flag as "in need of moderator intervention"?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, languages

I flag a lot of questions that ultimately are closed, but I fail to understand how to flag them. Recently I received a declined flag, pointing me to [the Help Center page on the Flag Posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). However, this site also does not tell me how to flag the post in question - which was in some non-English language.

I found an [FAQ here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/947526) after the declined flag. However, this is not enough for me. I'd like to have options that speak for themselves, and a documentation that helps in corner cases.

How should I proceed with non-English posts? Why is "in need of moderator intervention" wrong? Why are the other options better? How can I find that out without asking on here, or hunting down some hidden FAQ?

Related, but possibly out of scope, how should I deal with questions that belong on some other SO site, which is not in the list?

EDIT: I asked for a documentation update: [Documentation: Warn against using "in need of moderator attention" flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362391/documentation-warn-against-using-in-need-of-moderator-attention-flag)

Comment: Questions that aren't in English, can be flagged as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: That is already stated in the FAQ. Why is it wrong to flag it otherwise? How can I learn about that, without reading the FAQ or your comment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is "in need of moderator intervention" wrong?

Because they don't need to act upon these kind of posts. They're not going to translate it; they're going to *close* it as 'A community-specific reason' → 'Not written in English'. That's something the community (3k+ users) can do as well, so instead of increasing the ♦ moderator workload which is already high, just flag it to be closed. Hopefully, the Close Vote review queue will take care of it.

> Related, but possibly out of scope, how should I deal with questions that belong on some other SO site, which is not in the list?

Same story. Flag it to be closed; there's an option 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network' and you can choose from a list of target sites. If the site is not mentioned, and you're absolutely sure it's a **good** question which belongs on another site, you can use a custom moderator flag.

> How can I find that out without asking on here, or hunting down some hidden FAQ?

Yes, I agree that this is hard to know by just reading the privileges page. The only I can say about this is that it's the sixth and last option, the most advanced one, and since one of the previous ones applies, you should've chosen that one. Also, on sites where the ♦ moderator workload isn't that high (like [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) where I'm a moderator), the flag would probably be marked helpful (though I would've written something to tell you to use standard flags the next time).

Comment: So I guess moderators have more important things to do. How can I, as a non-moderator, close the question? How can I see that contacting the moderators is the wrong thing to do? How can I see what the flag should look like instead?

Comment: You can't close it, unless you have 3k reputation.

Comment: "How can I, as a non-moderator, close the question?" - for now, you can flag. After you have 3000 points, you can cast a close vote. 5 close votes will get the question closed (so it takes 5 people). You can also single-handedly vote to close a question if you have a gold tag badge in one of the tags on the question (_and_ have those 3000 points).

Comment: OK, let me rephrase. With less than 3k, what should I do and how do I know (in general, not me personally) that this is the right thing to do? I honestly don't understand how I should have known that the moderator option is wrong, and some other option is correct. There's no documentation, and just having declined flags doesn't help me understand the reasons.

Comment: @C-Otto so your question is pretty much why is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680) not in the documentation [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: @George Partially. Having that fixed would help in the very specific denied flag that lead me here. In general I'd like to see a strong message that explains when moderator flags should (not) be used, and what to do instead in case the other options also don't seem to match.

Comment: @C-Otto The mod flag should only be used if you see the post as problematic and no other flag applies. The mods are there for the cases where the community can't handle the situation on its own.

Comment: @yivi Good, I agree and understand. How should I have known that?

Comment: @C-Otto Truth to be told, I learnt that lesson with a couple of rejected mod flags (and by hanging around in meta). I'm not aware of any clear cut policy / help-text, although it may exist. I agree it should exist (or be easier to discover if it does).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362391/documentation-warn-against-using-in-need-of-moderator-attention-flag

Comment: @C-Otto many things on this site you can only really properly know by not acting too soon but rather hanging back and reading meta content and /or visiting a chat room. Even things highlighted in the documentation are still often misunderstood, especially in the area of flagging and voting.

Comment: That's a problem smell, not a solution :)

Comment: @C-Otto "How should I have known that?" .. the flag description ("A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!") tells you exactly that.

Comment: @Tom The problem was not listed "above", though. And in my previous understanding I required a moderator to deal with the issue, for example by closing the question. I added all the details necessary (although short and to the point).

Comment: @C-Otto "The problem was not listed "above", though" ... like the description said ...

Comment: @Tom I don't get it.

Comment: The description says "When none of the above flags matches, use 'In need of moderation attention'" and you say "none of the above flags matches, though" .. That's exactly what the description said and not an argument against it (Your sentence sounds like you tried to argue against the clarity of that description)

Comment: Since this was bumped: This is about flagging, but the close reason *"A community-specific reason"* → *"Not written in English"* could be mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to reduce the work-load for the "diamond moderators", when "user moderators" can deal with the problem. A user moderator is anyone with enough reputation, while a diamond moderator is someone who was either elected by the community or is a Stack Overflow company employee/admin.

Going through the flags available, many of them are handled by user moderators. What you should have done in this case is pick "Should be closed". You get another menu of options where you can pick why it should be closed. The right course of action for a post in a foreign language is to flag as should be closed -> unclear what you are asking.

The question is then handled by up to 5 high reputation users who must all agree that the question should be closed (for whatever reason), before the question is put "on hold".

"In need of moderator intervention" is used for special cases that don't fit any of the other categories. It should mainly be used when someone is breaking the rules of the site or abusing their previligies. These flags go to diamond moderators, so it helps if you be specific and if applicable provide a link to the problematic post.

Comment: The real problem here, IMO, is that sub-3k users don't get the option to enter a write-in close reason when flagging a question to be closed. For unusual cases that are not covered by the standard "canned" close reasons, that makes it tempting and natural to resort to the one type of flag that *does* offer a write-in option.