# Documentation: Warn against using "in need of moderator attention" flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderators

Based on my issue discussed in [When should I flag as "in need of moderator intervention"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362386/when-should-i-flag-as-in-need-of-moderator-intervention/362388?noredirect=1#comment551226_362388) I'd like the documentation at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts to be updated.

In addition to the existing documentation, I'd like to see a strong message that discourages me from using the "in need of moderator attention" flag when there is no need for moderator attention (I don't know the details!). This message could be something along the lines of:

> Just use 'Unclear what you're asking' if you just need the question to
>   be closed and the other options don't match. Don't annoy the moderators!

As a non-moderator user with currently less than 3k points I feel uninformed about the details of flagging. A question that doesn't clearly fit into the available options often leads me to flag decisions that others (moderators?) don't agree with. In order to help me and other users find the correct flag, the documentation should be more helpful and also discuss corner cases.

(As mentioned in the linked question, explicitly stating what to do with non-English questions might also be a good idea!)

Comment: Think of moderators as sleeping dragons, you don't want to disturb them unless for something important.

Comment: The advice _Just use 'Unclear what you're asking' if you just need the question to be closed and the other options don't match_ is NOT what you should do! Questions should only be closed if there's a valid reason for it. You should not flag clear questions as unclear because you feel they should be closed because of another reason.

Comment: I also disagree with the "do not _annoy_ the moderators" line. That's not the angle to pursue. The idea is that moderators are _exception handlers_, so you should avoid using that option unless your flag deals with a real exception... and not because moderators are easily annoyed and you taste fine with ketchup.

Comment: @AndyG OK. Please let us add that to the documentation then!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: So what should I do for reasons that are not offered as an option (non-English as an example)?

Comment: @yivi: I agree that the wording is suboptimal :)

Comment: In the case of non-English, you have to chose _"unclear"_ not because "nothing else fits". You choose "unclear" because from the point of view of an English speaking reader, something in a different language is **definitely unclear**.

Comment: @yivi OK, I agree. Although this might seem straightforward, I'd prefer this to be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @yivi I used the term *disturb* rather than *annoy*, as in *disturb their slumber* ... for something exceptional.

Comment: In the non-English example, it is unclear (for most readers, at least, because they won't understand a word). For other reasons, you should check the meta, and you can ask a question if none exist. Non-English questions are discussed in the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/7296893)

Comment: @AndyG They prefer to be thought of as [ninjas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters). Or [dogs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf). Or [ninja dogs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements).

Answer (score 4):

Er... no.

> Just use 'Unclear what you're asking' if you just need the question to be closed and the other options don't match. Don't annoy the moderators!

So we're going to go from clogging the mod queue to clogging the close vote queue? That's not a good solution.

1. Only flag things for moderators that you can't handle in any other way. If there's a more specific flag, use that instead. The mod flag *already tells you this* (emphasis mine):

   > **A problem not listed above** that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!
2. If a question needs closing, *please pick a proper reason*. Do **NOT** use one flag as a roll-up for any and all issues. Remember, someone is going to review your flag

Comment: Now I'm more confused than before. What should I do instead, when there's a question for which I'm unable to find a proper flag? Currently I read your answer as "ask the mods with a proper reason"?

Comment: @C-Otto - If a question doesn't match any of the existing close reasons then it probably doesn't need to be closed. Not all bad questions are closeable. But if you're sure there's a problem that needs to be addressed then yes, use a moderator flag if no other flag suits it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we should have it say the same thing as what frequently gets said on Meta and in [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> ## When should I flag something as needs ♦ moderator attention?
>
> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those
>   (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally
>   happen and cannot be handled by normal community moderation. Do not
>   use this flag for problems that can be handled by voting, editing, or
>   using a more specific flag.
>
> Examples of when to flag for moderator attention include, but are not
>   limited to:
>
> - Suspected plagarism
> - Suspected vote fraud
> - Edit wars