# Does Stack Overflow follow multiple languages?

Tags: discussion, support, languages

---

I'm asking this question just out of curiosity. Recently I found a question [Como modificar la barra de -webkit-scrollbar-thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024163/como-modificar-la-barra-de-webkit-scrollbar-thumb) and it's not written in English...

---

> [image: Here is the image in case it disappears]

---

- Is it a valid question?
- Does Stack Overflow allow multiple languages?

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is English-only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Stack Overflow is **English**-only.

This question should be closed as *"Unclear what you're asking"*.
(And that's what happened)

Comment: Yeah , You are right

Comment: The comments seem to indicate the question is in Spanish. In that case, it can be re-asked on [Spanish SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Yeah , but I'm talking respective to SO(this English version)

Comment: It's closed now.

Comment: Not closed , still [on hold]

Comment: That's "closed", @MasterDarkNight.

Comment: But , it says [on hold]

Comment: That's what happens when a question is closed.

Comment: Okay , i get it