# Should non-English questions be marked for deletion or editing?

Tags: support, languages

I just failed a test while reviewing the triage queue. Marking a Russian question as *requires editing*.

The question was a valid question, although a little vague. But marked as spam. Should any non-English question be marked as spam? Or should the OP be given a chance to edit?

[image]

Comment: OP still has the chance to edit the question and flag for undeletion, although on hindsight I should have closed it first

Comment: Good to know. The duplicate of my question says it should be closed. In future I'll mark to close and I wont feel so guilty if they can flag for reverse the close.

Comment: @Lex, also, please remember than the _"Require Editing"_ button is meant for posts where the post is basically fine, but could use some help from other users's edits. If only the author can fix the post (as in a post written in a different language), _"Requires editing"_ is the **wrong** choice.

Comment: Thanks @yivi I guess I was thinking the author could edit the post to change the language. In future I'll mark as off topic.